# Parsing Phrases with a Pipe Character Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I've been working on my Safari extension for saving content to [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/) and have been working on enhancing my title parsing for bookmarks. For example, an article that I recently saved has a  tag that looks like this:

> Report: Bing Users Disproportionately Affected By Malware Redirects | TechCrunch

I want to use the JavaScript in my Safari extension to remove all of the text after the pipe character so that I can make the final bookmark look neater once it is saved to Instapaper.

I've attempted the title parsing successfully in a couple of similar cases using blocks of code that look like this:

```
if(safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title.search(' - ') != -1) {
            console.log(safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title);
            console.log(safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title.search(' - '));
            var parsedTitle = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title.substring(0, safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title.search(' - '));
            console.log(parsedTitle);
};
```

I started getting thrown for a loop once I tried doing this same thing with the pipe character; however, since JavaScript uses it as a special character. I've tried several bits of code to try and solve this problem. The most recent looks like this (attempting to use regular expressions and escape the pipe character):

```
if(safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title.search('/\|') != -1) {
            console.log(safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title);
            console.log(safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title.search('/\|'));
            var parsedTitle = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title.substring(0, safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title.search('/\|'));
            console.log(parsedTitle);
};
```

If anybody could give me a tip that works for this, your help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is malformed. It should be:

```
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title.search(/\|/)
```

Note the lack of quotes; I'm using a regex literal here. Also, regex literals need to be bound by `/`.

Instead of searching and then replacing, you can simply do a replace with the following regex:

```
str = str.replace(/\|.*$/, "");
```

This will remove everything after the `|` character if it exists.

Comment: Worked PERFECTLY! Thank you!!! I'm still learning how to use regular expressions and was just totally stumped on this one!

Comment: @canisbos I planned on doing so. The answer hadn't been up long enough for me to accept it last time I was on.

Comment: @Jordan, Oh. I didn't realize there was a waiting period. Sorry for being officious.

Comment: @Vivin could you share how you might save the string after the | to a new variable?

Comment: @chandlervdw You could simply do this `str = str.replace(/^.*\|/, "");`. This will remove everything up to the `|`, so all you have is the string remaining after the `|`.